# iOS login segue fix

Tags: ios

This is the success parameter to my login which is under the closing bracket in viewDidload

```
//check whether it's a login or register
NSString* command = (sender.tag==1)?@"register":@"login";
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command", fldUsername.text, @"username", hashedPassword, @"password", nil];
//make the call to the web API
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //result returned
    NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil && [[res objectForKey:@"IdUser"] intValue]>0) {
        [[API sharedInstance] setUser: res];
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        //show message to the user
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[res objectForKey:@"username"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    } else {
        //error
        [UIAlertView error:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
    }
}];

}
```

And this is the programatic connection in the view that I want to show when the user is authorized

```
-(void)viewDidload
[super viewDidLoad];
{
if (![[API sharedInstance] isAuthorized]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];
}
```

The problem is when I enter saved logged in credentials in my database (i.e. username: user1 password: password) I get the correct UIAlert I'm supposed to receive (Logged in - Welcome user1). But when i enter (username:user1 password: fake password) I still get the logged in UIAlert. Also if i try to register a new user from the app i.e. (username:user2 password: password 2) I get an authentication failed UIAlert. Also my segue doesn't actually happen when I enter valid credentials.  Any tips?

Updated: logout delegate

```
-(void)logout {
//logout the user from the server, and also upon success destroy the local authorization
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"logout", @"command", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
   //logged out from server
   [API sharedInstance].user = nil;
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:nil];
}];
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting - [[API sharedInstance] setIsAuthorized: NO]; Because if user logs out and relogin then this paran should be set to NO for next time. I guess that's creating problem in your case, when next time you tries with wrong password, that param has already been set to YES. Just a guess as there is not much code for logout.

Comment: theere are errors set to show if the login/register is incomplete. Also I've already tested the app and am just importing it to my own using the same code.

Comment: On Logout action, as well on login screen viewWillAppear event - try this: [API sharedInstance].isAuthorized = NO and [API sharedInstance].user = nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //result returned
    NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil && [[res objectForKey:@"IdUser"] intValue]>0) {
        [[API sharedInstance] setUser: res];
        [API sharedInstance].isAuthorized = YES; //Added
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        //show message to the user
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[res objectForKey:@"username"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    } else {
        [[API sharedInstance] setUser: nil]; //Added
        [API sharedInstance].isAuthorized = NO; //Added
        //error
        [UIAlertView error:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
    }
}];
```

Find the lines with inline comments `//Added` and try those in your code. Also as mentioned update login view -> viewWillAppear and logout method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that reminds me, the original app has an initial view (public) that must check for the parameter your hinting at: when the user clicks a certain action it takes them on to the login screen/ i just wanted to use the login screen I forgot to parse for any checked instances.

Comment: I honestly don't see where I am even specifying what view controller is set to show when the view is dismissed.